# Best practice for tracing task on your server

Tags: python, nginx, fastapi, trace

Im currently on building a small web server(apprx 1M req per month) using [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) and [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/ko/).

I wanna trace the task for monitoring. For example, to deal with a request, the API server would execute a series of functions as below.

func A()
func B()
func C()

**each function would write a log which I want to trace. As multiple users can connect to the server, I want to identify each task.**

Unique ID for a request seems a good way I think. Then I need to build uuid generator and put the id in the request header (right?).

The Question is,
how do you trace your request? I'm curious what is common and easy way to accomplish it.

Thanks in advance!

I tried to put a custom header(UUID) into request header. Is it the only way?

Comment: Are you using user authentication as a token or session?

Comment: Look into the [`starlette-context` library](https://starlette-context.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), which will set up a [`ContextVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) with e.g. the request ID. You can then use a [`LoggerAdapter`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output) to automatically log this ID with every `logging` call.

Comment: @EunhoJeong no not yet. we don't manage users atm. but someday we will!